# Google Play Services change my style (more precisely remove)

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-styles

After I added Google Play Service to build.gradle file, my CheckBox lost customized style and icon on ActionBar has been changed (now I have arrow).

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/login_cb_remember"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Remember me"
    android:checked="false" />
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

style.xml:

```
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#232323</item>
        <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBoxAppTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

style_apptheme.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="CheckBoxAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
      <item name="android:button">@drawable/apptheme_btn_check_holo_light</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

This situation began to happen after added:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

Comment: I don't think that it is because a google play library ... I had similar issue (but with Buttons) and it was because appcompat v7 library ... quick fix is to use  `public class MyCheckbox extends CheckBox { /* add constructors with super call only*/ }` ... <= ok it looks like programming by permutation ... but it isn't ... why it would work? Internally AppCompat library replace every `CheckBox` with `TintCheckBox` on `addView/inflate` (at last time i've check the source) ... It will not do this if you are using different class ...

Comment: @Selvin, thanks! You made my day!

Comment: But I still have problem with Actionbar icon. I set:

Comment: R.drawable.ic_drawer but I have arrow...